non string fields in official metadata extension
Does anyone know if its possible to have non string additional fields when using the official token metadata extension?
The interface just has a     :
pub additional_metadata: Vec<(String, String)>,

But I would like to explicitly store things as, say, a u8, so that i can change the value of that field without potentially having a resize of the whole account when the string changes.
I note there is an 'emit' function... is the idea that you can just write your own version of the interface that has your own fields and then write an emit function that tells people how to decode it? But if so how does anyone know what program to call to get that emit function?
I'm a bit confused about how exactly the extension is meant to be used more generically than the example in the repo.

All fields must be strings in the additional metadata portion. If you want to store numbers, you could use base64 encoding and pad it to a certain amount, that way you don't need to worry about resizing.
And for your second question, yes, the point of emit is that anyone can implement the spl-token-metadata interface, including that emit instruction. Since the instruction is well-defined, with a fixed discriminator and inputs, it's possible for any caller to create an emit instruction and call your program with it.
The caller just needs to know that your program implements the spl-token-metadata interface.
